# Resize Listbox with UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

I have this peace of a code for resizing userform `sameCustomerForm` window:

```
Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "User32.dll" () As Long

Private Declare Function GetWindowLong _
  Lib "User32.dll" Alias "GetWindowLongA" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
     ByVal nIndex As Long) _
  As Long

Private Declare Function SetWindowLong _
  Lib "User32.dll" Alias "SetWindowLongA" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
     ByVal nIndex As Long, _
     ByVal dwNewLong As Long) _
  As Long

Private Const WS_THICKFRAME As Long = &H40000
Private Const GWL_STYLE As Long = -16

Public Sub FormResizable()

Dim lStyle As Long
Dim hWnd As Long
Dim RetVal

hWnd = GetForegroundWindow

lStyle = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) Or WS_THICKFRAME
RetVal = SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, lStyle)

End Sub
```

In UserForm `sameCustomerForm` code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Call FormResizable
End Sub
```

Then I have a Listbox `lstSelector` on userform `sameCustomerForm`. I would like to stick `lstSelector` to sides of userform like you can do in Visual Studio while designing WinForms application with anchoring objects to sides of a Form.

Any ideas how it is possible to achieve in Excel userform?

---

**EDIT:**

This is almost working. Everything resizes in proportions now except the bottom. I am missing bottom scrollbar on resizing window if `.Height = sameCustomerForm.Height / 1` and if `.Height = sameCustomerForm.Height / 2` bottom scrollbar is way to high. Have some problems with sticking bottom to the bottom...

```
Private Sub UserForm_Resize()

With sameCustomerForm.lstSelector
    .Width = sameCustomerForm.Width - 12
    .Height = sameCustomerForm.Height / 2
    .Top = 54
    .Left = 0
End With

End Sub
```

---

**EDIT2:**

This one did the trick:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Resize()

With sameCustomerForm.lstSelector
    .Width = sameCustomerForm.Width - 12
    .Height = sameCustomerForm.InsideHeight - 54
    .Top = 54
    .Left = 0
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use your userform metrics to achieve this.
Below is an example which uses buttons to dock listbox by sides:
[image]

**Update**
Refactored the code to use `InsideHeight` and `InsideWidth` UserForms' properties.

Here is buttons' code:

```
Private Sub bottomButton_Click()
' dock bottom
With myForm.lstSelector
    .Width = myForm.InsideWidth
    .Height = myForm.InsideHeight / 3
    .Top = myForm.InsideHeight - .Height
    .Left = 0
End With
End Sub

Private Sub leftButton_Click()
' dock left
With myForm.lstSelector
    .Width = myForm.InsideWidth / 3 ' just for example
    .Top = 0
    .Left = 0
    .Height = myForm.InsideHeight
End With
End Sub

Private Sub rightButton_Click()
' dock right
With myForm.lstSelector
    .Width = myForm.InsideWidth / 3 ' just for example
    .Top = 0
    .Left = myForm.InsideWidth - .Width
    .Height = myForm.InsideHeight
End With

End Sub

Private Sub stickButton_Click()
' stick
With myForm.lstSelector
    .Width = myForm.InsideWidth ' just for example
    .Top = 0
    .Left = 0
    .Height = myForm.InsideHeight
End With

End Sub

Private Sub topButton_Click()
'  dock up
With myForm.lstSelector
    .Width = myForm.InsideWidth ' just for example
    .Top = 0
    .Left = 0
    .Height = myForm.InsideHeight / 3
End With

End Sub
```

This is a general idea how to dock it to different sides. In case you implemented a resizable UserForm (manually or by workflow) - the idea will still the same, but you should think of putting those handlers to `UserForm_Resize` event.

In case you need to anchor it somewhere else - you'll have to calculate positions proportions.

Comment: The userform object has a Resize event which you can use to change the dimensions of the controls on the form.

Comment: @jkpieterse Yeap, I know, noted that event just under the code section. This is only general idea of how it works, as I also noted.

Comment: Thanks for that! Now I have to figure out how to fix it by top and left and make right and bottom size within userform resize...

Comment: @hatman to fix it top and left simply use `your_control.Top =0` and `your_control.Left = 0`. In order to get width and height you will have to take a part of your UserForm's width and height parameters accordingly.

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak Ok, there is `.Top`, `.Left`, `.Right`, what is command for Bottom? See my edit in original question

Comment: @hatman There is no Bottom property, so you have to operate by Height. You are taking `.Height = sameCustomerForm.Height / 2` which is the half of userForm's height, so it will never stick it to bottom. If you try `.Height = sameCustomerForm.InsideHeight` it will take the UserForm's height without title bar